# Same-sex divorce

Tags: united-states, divorce

In [Obergefell v. Hodges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obergefell_v._Hodges), the Supreme Court held that there was a constitutional right to same-sex marriage.  Does this automatically extend to divorce, or is it possible that the Supreme Court will need to rule on a case in the future where a state refused to grant a same-sex couple a divorce because state divorce law only covers opposite-sex couples?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The court said in Obergefell (emphasis mine):

> Under the Constitution, same-sex couples seek in marriage *the same legal treatment as opposite-sex couples*, and it would disparage their choices and diminish their personhood to deny them this right.

If same-sex couples are to be given in marriage the "same legal treatment" as opposite-sex couples, the divorce process must also be the same.